# Disable View, Share and More menu from graph in Grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-variable, grafana-api, grafana-alerts

How to disable the View, Share and More menu from the Grafana [Panel Menu --> View, Share, More–Export CSV, JSON etc;]. I don't want to show these options to user.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:
I have provided a solution to this on the grafana community forum.

**You will have to update your CSS to hide all the extra options.
Have a look at [this Link](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/12019#issuecomment-889696637)**